# Deleting selected data from database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

May I know how to delete rows from the `GridView` using a `LinkButton`? Codes I find in google are using databound `GridView`. I'm binding the information depending on information selected with the `DropDownList`. Thanks

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username;
    username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Equals("Expired"))
    {
        SqlConnection conn4 = new SqlConnection(My connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        string mySQL2;
        mySQL2 = 
            "SELECT Title,MessageStatus From Table_Message WHERE Username ='" 
            + username 
            + "' AND MessageStatus = 'Expired' AND Method = 'Email'";
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySQL2, conn4);
        conn4.Open();

        DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds3);
        //Execute the sql command
        GridView1.DataSource = ds3;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        conn4.Close();

    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Equals("Pending"))
    {
        SqlConnection conn3 = new SqlConnection(My connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1;
        string mySQL;
        mySQL = 
            "SELECT Title,MessageStatus From Table_Message WHERE Username ='" 
            + username 
            + "' AND MessageStatus = 'Pending' AND Method = 'Email'";
        adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(mySQL, conn3);
        conn3.Open();

        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        adapter1.Fill(ds2);
        //Execute the sql command
        GridView1.DataSource = ds2;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        conn3.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing anonymous users to access the listing:

This could be an option:

1. Create a delete.aspx
2. In your query do fetch Primary Key column (Ex: Id, UId...)
3. In grid view make DataKeyNames = "Id"
4. In linkbutton`s onclick Event, redirect user to delete.aspx?Id='Your data id'
5. The delete.aspx could only be accessed by the authorize users. Saves accidental data loss.
6. In delete.aspx put a delete button, and it`s onclick event delete the record with that Unique Id.
7. This could be a way doing things securely.

If you are displaying listing to only authorize users, then you may write the delete code  with ajax:

- OnClientClick(): Write javascript functio that send request to: `delete.aspx?Id='Id'`, delete record there.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the following steps

1) Map the DataKeyNames of grid to the primary key of your table

2) Have on LinkButton as

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/DELETE.GIF"
                            AlternateText="Delete" CommandName="DeleteUser" CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Delete"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
```

3) Bind the command argument in rowdatabound event

```
 protected void GvwUser_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        ImageButton imgBtnDelete;


        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {            
            imgBtnDelete = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnDelete");
            imgBtnDelete.CommandArgument = gvwUser.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        }
    }
```

4)In the code behind write the implementation as

```
protected void GvwUser_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
int userId = 0;
if (e.CommandName.Equals("DeleteUser"))
        {
            //get the user id
            userId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

            //GetUser will delete the user
            if (DeleteUser(userId) > 0)
            {
             Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Delete", "alert('User Deleted.');", true);
            }
}
```